# system modal dialog in GTK

Tags: c++, linux, modal-dialog, gtk

I am trying to create GtkDialog with system wide Modal property i.e. when the dialog is opened no other window should get focus. There is an option for making it modal using GtkDialogFlag but that is not system wide modal.

Comment: Bad idea. What if your application freezes and there's no way to use System Monitor or a terminal to kill it? Is it so important that your user *cannot* do *anything* else until he answers your modal dialog?

Comment: Actually, I am implementing a dialog for shutdown and reboot. So I need that user should not focus anything else unless answered the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

This is an utterly *horrible* idea, but you can override the "focus-out-event" handler for your window and have it call `gtk_window_present`.

Something like gksu does:

```
static gboolean
focus_out_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventFocus *event, gpointer user_data)
{
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW(widget));
  return TRUE;
}

//in your initialization code for your window...
/* make sure that our window will always have the focus */
g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(mywindow), "focus-out-event",
          G_CALLBACK(focus_out_cb), NULL);
```

This hopefully has the added benefit of if your application *does* freeze, the signal for focus-out-event will probably not be handled.  I'm not sure how GTK does UI threading though, but I think this should be true.